Page.title alignment is not working using Flet in Python
I am starting to study Python and Flet's lib, and I am trying to center align the title (page.title) of page or app, but I couldn't find anything specific about this anywhere. I looked everywhere with no success. I only found instructions on how to do it in the body of the app.
I tried page.horizontal_alignment = ft.CrossAlignment.CENTER, but as said before, it just aligned the content of the body of the app.

page.title is the title displayed at the top of the Brother. The title in the page is created and placed in a text control. Run the following example. def main(page: ft.Page):     page.title = "App title"     title = ft.Text('Page Title')     page.add(ft.Row([title], alignment=ft.MainAxisAlignment.CENTER))

No. This is not what I want.
This create a title inside de main page of the app. I want to center align the title of the app inside the app bar (the one that remains aside the minimize, maximaze and close icons.

If you are talking about the app bar, see here.

I already did it before. Wasn't helpfull!
